# Access Div tag in Page from Masterpage codebehind

Tags: webforms

I need access div in a page.

### page.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody1" runat="server">
<div class="table-responsive">
   <div class="card card-authentication1 mx-auto my-5" id="div_Payment" runat="server"></div>
</div
</asp:Content>
```

### masterpage

```
protected void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlControl control = (HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody1").FindControl("div_Payment");

HtmlControl control = (HtmlControl)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody1").FindControl("div_Payment");
            control.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
```

no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
HtmlControl MyDiv = (HtmlControl)Page
  .Master
  .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody1")
  .FindControl("Panel1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This is fun"></asp:Label>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="card card-authentication1 mx-auto my-5" id="div_Payment" runat="server">xxxx</div>
    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

code behind on master page:

```
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label MyLabel1 = 
            (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)MainContent.FindControl("Label1");
        Debug.Print("Value of Lable 1 on child page = " + MyLabel1.Text);


        HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)MainContent.FindControl("div_Payment");

        Debug.Print("Inner text = " + MyDiv.InnerText);
```

so, you don't have to "find" the first "content" control - that will exist.

(you could, but it not required).

Comment: hi Kallal,
HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)ContentPlaceHolderBody1.FindControl("div_Payment"); i tried this but got error ContentPlaceHolderBody1 the name does not exits

Comment: Check your master page. The name for ContentPlaceHodlerBody1 should exist in your master page. the "id" we use here is the name of the content place holder from master page - in my master page it has a id of "MainContent". Sometimes there are two placeholders, but the content control "id" is the one from master page, not the child page.